# Fontspec error: My favorite fonts could not be identified

Tags: xepersian

I'm trying to add Persian text to my document, however, my favorite fonts (which already have been installed on Windows 10 and I use them on Microsoft Word) can not be identified.

```
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"!! The font "XB Niloofar" cannot be found.!!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"!! The font "Yas" cannot be found.!!
! fontspec error: "font-not-found"!! The font "IranNastaliq" cannot be found.!!
```

Here is the document I'm trying to compile:

```
‎\documentclass[11pt]{exam}‎
‎\usepackage{xepersian}‎

‎\settextfont[Scale=1]‎{XB Niloofar}‎
‎\setdigitfont[Scale=1]{Yas}‎
‎\setlatintextfont[Scale=0.9]{Times New Roman}‎
\defpersianfont\nastaliq[Scale=1]{IranNastaliq}‎

‎\begin{document}‎ 
\textbf{سلام}‎
‎\end{document}‎
```

Comment: If you have any local font caches in your `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.texlive2019\texmf-var\`, delete them. They might be hiding system fonts.

Comment: I did it but it still gives the same error

Comment: You might also check the family names of the fonts with `otfinfo -i`, or try loading them by filename, which should always work.

Comment: Would you please let me know how I can check  it?

Comment: Try if the fonts are found if you don't use xepersian but only fontspec. (Only as a test, it doesn't need to give senseful output).

Comment: If you open up a command (Win-R, CMD), you can `DIR "C:\Windows\Fonts\XB*"` and you should see the filename, e.g. `C:\Windows\Fonts\CB Niloofar.ttf`.  If it's not there, it might have been installed for you only..

Comment: When you have the filename, `otfinfo -i "C:\Windows\Fonts\XB Niloofar.ttf"`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I got this error: !Undefined control sequence. \settextfont

Comment: Use \setmainfont instead.

Comment: @Davislor: I tried `DIR "C:\Windows\Fonts\XB*"` and I got `Volume in drive C is OS - Volume Serial Number is 04D2-B7D3- Directory of C:\Windows\Fonts - File Not Found`. How can I fix it?

Comment: It sounds like what probably happened is that you installed the fonts for yourself, instead of for all users. Extract the font files you downloaded into a temporary folder, select them, right-click, and select "Install for all users."

Comment: @Davislor: Thank you so much, I can fix it. However, my problem has been solved only by your below answer: `\settextfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
             BoldFont = *Bd ,
             ItalicFont = *It ,
             BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
             Extension = .ttf
            ]{XB Niloofar}`. Would you please let me know how I can fix it with `\settextfont[Scale=1]‎{XB Niloofar}‎`?

Comment: That form of the command is deprecated. It’s always been inconsistent what works and what doesn’t between XeTeX and LuaTeX and between Windows and Linux. However, if you use the family name returned by `otfinfo -i`, it theoretically should work.

Comment: `\settextfont[Scale=1]{XB Niloofar}` in a current texlive 2019 works fine for me on windows. But you should really check if it works with fontspec alone. Your error message looks unusual and xepersian changes some fontspec internals.

Comment: The heavy-duty approach to make that syntax work is to create a file named `XB Niloofar.fontspec` with the correct options for your installation. That should let you work around just about any problem without changing your source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way to load fonts in `fontspec` is by filename.  You can try:

```
\settextfont[Scale = 1.0 ,
             BoldFont = *Bd ,
             ItalicFont = *It ,
             BoldItalicFont = *BdIt ,
             Extension = .ttf
            ]{XB Niloofar}
```

If your fonts are named `XB Niloofar.ttf`, `XB NiloofarBd.ttf`, etc.

If that still doesn’t work, see if `\setmainfont` with the same options does.  This is probably not what you want, but it can confirm that the issue is or is not with `fontspec`.

You can run `fc-match "XB Niloofar"` to see if XeTeX can find the font and `luaotfload-tool --find "XB Niloofar"` to see if LuaTeX can.

Also make sure the fonts are installed for all users, in the `%WINDIR%\Fonts\` directory.  Separately, if you have any local font caches in `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%\.texlive2019\texmf-var\`, delete them.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not work.

Comment: Okay, can either `fc-match` or `luaotfload-tool --find` find it?

Comment: Well done! Thanks.

Comment: @Davislor: I have same problem after installing `TeXlive 2021` but that was fine in my previous `TeXlive 2019`. I opened `%WINDIR%\Fonts` folder but I couldn't find all fonts that I installed recently there but that fonts are listed in the control panel font folder. What's the wrong?

Comment: @C.F.G TeX Live can’t find fonts that you installed to your user account. Those go into a hidden directory in your user folder. You must install them either for all users, as an administrator, or to a folder in the local TeX tree (normally `C:\texlive\texmf-local`, but `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFLOCAL` is the way to look it up), or to a subfolder of your user TeX tree (normally `%USERPROFILE%\texmf`, but `kpsewhich --var-value=TEXMFHOME` is the way to look it up.)

Comment: @C.F.G Normally, you would install `.otf`, `.ttf` and `.otc` files for all users.. Delete the copies you have in your Fonts Control Panel, select the files you downloaded, right-click, and Install for All Users.

Comment: @C.F.G Install to a subdirectory of `TEXMFLOCAL` (such as `C:\texlive\texmf-local\fonts\opentype`) if you **only** use a font for TeX and don’t want it cluttering up your font menus. All legacy Type-1 or METAFONT fonts must also go in this tree.

Comment: @C.F.G Put them in `TEXMFHOME` if you are on a shared computer and want to install files for your own account only, or you are not an administrator.

Comment: @C.F.G Finally, put the fonts in your project directory, or in a subfolder that you call with `Path=./fonts/`, if you are going to archive a copy of that specific version of that specific font with that specific project, so you will never have to try to figure out which old version of the font your document needs, twenty years from now.